# Flink - what is the difference between an operator that forwards to a DiscardingSink vs sending nowhere?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Dataflow in Flink as follows:

Source -> Operator -> DiscardingSink

Is there any difference between that and one that has no Sink?

Source -> Operator ->

From my tests it seems to run the same, although in the first case I see that the operator and sink are chained and no records are sent from the sink. In the second case I can see that records are forwarded, but they have nowhere to go.

From my understanding the Operator will be filling up it's outgoing network buffers with records, and I would expect at some point to see back pressure, but that doesn't happen, so what are the semantics I should expect here?

Answer (score 0):

The back pressure only appears during shuffle.

Your examples are all chain or forward connections，there is no shuffle connection.

Maybe you can set the concurrency of the operator to be different, so that a shuffle connection will occur.

Comment: The core question is different. He wants to know what's the difference betweeen those two implementation.
Its not about when the backpreassure will appear. That thing was just his assumption of "what's the difference"